# Getting the original secretkey from hex format

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, aes

This is the hex format of a secret key used for AES encryption

```
00010203050607080A0B0C0D0F101112
```

Can i generate the original SecretKey format or byte array from this?

If so how?

Comment: I hope you're posting a modified hex value or the data you're protecting isn't important...

Comment: yes i am just posting for a test data hex key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons Codec to perform the hex decoding,

http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decodeHex(char[])

If you don't want use any libraries, you can also do this,

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger("7F" + str, 16).toByteArray();
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, 1, bytes.length-1, "AES");
```

You have to add an extra byte 0x7F to prevent BigInteger from stripping leading zeros or adding signed bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A [`SecretKey`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html) is an interface. What type was the implementation? J2SE has two implementing classes, [`KerberosKey`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/kerberos/KerberosKey.html) and [`SecretKeySpec`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html), both which have constructors with a byte array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What is the original SecretKey format?
Are you aware `byte[]` contains signed bytes valued from -128 to 127?
Would it hurt if you tried this:

```
byte[] key = {
  0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,
  0x0A,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x0F,0x10,0x11,0x12
};
```

Note: If you have values like 0x80 - 0xFF you'll need to cast them as (byte)0x80 - (byte)0xFF to avoid a warning about the range.